# Why is my Rails App failing to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk never accepts my app when I deploy it to their service. I've tried to fix all issues by reading the log and nothing seems to work. My development IDE is **Rubymine** / **ruby 2.4.5** / **Rails 5.2.0** / **Windows 10 Pro x64** / **Bundler verion 1.16.4**. The error that I am receiving is below. How can I successfully deploy my app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk??
In development, I have no issues with launching the app whasoever. I tried to launch the app with the fewest dependencies possible. I cleared the assets cache. I removed unnecessary files. Nothing seems to satisfy Elastic Beanstalk. (This is my very first time using the service)

**One note**: I am using actioncable for this particular app

**database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

**cable.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] %>
  channel_prefix: <%= ENV['CABLE_CHANNEL_PREFIX'] %>
```

**gems**

```
ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x64-mingw32]
```

**Error log**:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log
-------------------------------------
  gem 'loofah-activerecord'

  # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
  gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
  gem 'rails', '5.2.0' # '~>5.1.1' 5.1.6
  # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
  #gem 'derailed_benchmarks', group: :development

  gem 'pg', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.4'
  gem 'puma', '~> 2.16'


  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails'
  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.20'

  # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

  # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
  # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
  # gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
  # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
  # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
  gem 'redis'

  # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
  # gem 'bcrypt', '~>3.1.11', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw, :mingw]
  #gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', require: 'bcrypt'
  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.12'
  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

  group :test do
    gem 'capybara', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
    gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.0'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.2'
    gem 'rubocop-rspec'
    gem 'stripe-ruby-mock', '~> 2.5.4', require: 'stripe_mock'
    gem 'webmock'
  end

  group :development do
    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
    gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  end

  # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem


  platform :mswin, :mingw, :x64_mingw do
    gem 'tzinfo-data'
    gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw], group: :development
  end


  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  + '[' -d /var/app/ondeck/vendor/cache ']'
  + bundle install --deployment --local
  Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
  installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
  Your bundle only supports platforms ["x64-mingw32"] but your local platforms are
   ["ruby", "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

[2019-03-03T05:36:01.585Z] ERROR [27678] : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2019-03-03T05:36:01.586Z] INFO  [27678] : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"(TRUNCATED)...ling your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root\nusers on this machine.\nYour bundle only supports platforms [\"x64-mingw32\"] but your local platforms are\n[\"ruby\", \"x86_64-linux\"], and there's no compatible match between those two\nlists. \nHook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":16,"events":[]}],"truncated":"true"}
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.557Z] DEBUG [27906] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.557Z] DEBUG [27906] : Checking if the command processor should execute...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.559Z] DEBUG [27906] : Checking whether the command is applicable to instance (i-02c427cad88fc3a3e)..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.559Z] INFO  [27906] : Command is applicable to this instance (i-02c427cad88fc3a3e)..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.559Z] DEBUG [27906] : Checking if the received command stage is valid..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.559Z] INFO  [27906] : No stage_num in command. Valid stage..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] INFO  [27906] : Received command CMD-TailLogs: {"execution_data"=>"*", "instance_ids"=>["i-02c43eeewfefwfw"], "data"=>"betetet--reeetetetete5", "command_name"=>"CMD-TailLogs", "api_version"=>"1.0", "resource_name"=>"AWSEBAutoScalingGroup", "request_id"=>"b100000-2222-2222-2222-22222222"}
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] INFO  [27906] : Command processor should execute command.
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] DEBUG [27906] : Storing current stage..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] DEBUG [27906] : Stage_num does not exist. Not saving null stage. Returning..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] DEBUG [27906] : Reading config file: /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws-eb-stack.properties
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] DEBUG [27906] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_ContainerConfigFileContent||commands..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.560Z] DEBUG [27906] : Retrieving metadata for key: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext||_API||_Commands..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.561Z] INFO  [27906] : Found enabled addons: 
["logstreaming", "logpublish"].
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Updating Command definition of addon logstreaming.
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Updating Command definition of addon logpublish.
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] DEBUG [27906] : Loaded definition of Command CMD-TailLogs.
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Executing CMD-TailLogs
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Executing command: CMD-TailLogs...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Executing command CMD-TailLogs activities...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] DEBUG [27906] : Setting environment variables..
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.562Z] INFO  [27906] : Running AddonsBefore for command CMD-TailLogs...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.563Z] DEBUG [27906] : Running stages of Command CMD-TailLogs from stage 0 to stage 0...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.563Z] INFO  [27906] : Running stage 0 of command CMD-TailLogs...
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.563Z] DEBUG [27906] : Loaded 1 actions for stage 0.
[2019-03-03T05:39:21.563Z] INFO  [27906] : Running 1 of 1 actions: TailLogs...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Gemfile.lock` was generated on Windows (`x64-mingw32` platform) and contains versions of gems that aren't compatible with Linux. But Amazon only supports the `ruby` or the `x86_64-linux` platform.

```
Your bundle only supports platforms ["x64-mingw32"] but your local platforms are
["ruby", "x86_64-linux"], and there's no compatible match between those two lists.
```

This basically means you cannot use your current `Gemfile.lock` on Linux machines (or Macs) at all. You will need to run `bundle update` (instead of `bundle install`) on that OSs to allow bundler to find a new matching set of gem versions.

Of cause, this is a bit risky because then you might run other gem versions on your production system than in your development environment and therefore I suggest to run the test again before actually switching to the new version when deploying.

When you plan to work on Ruby on Rails apps on a regular base I suggest switching to Linux as your local development environment. Linux in a virtual machine or via docker image might be another option for you.

Comment: I whole heartedly agree.  I don't know how anyone can develop rails applications from Windows - just thinking about it gives me a headache.

Comment: I will use my instance of Ubuntu to create a mock Rails 5.2.0 app. Pull out the defaults and place them in the gemfile...Reinitialize the gems and have them all configured for Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although you should probably use a virtual machine of some kind for developing ruby/rails for a production environment, for now try changing this in your gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end
```

You can remove this to test your deploy:

```
platform :mswin, :mingw, :x64_mingw do
  gem 'tzinfo-data'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw], group: :development
end
```

You should only need rubocop in development as well so move it inside the development block as well.

Then run

```
bundle install
```

Then try your deploy again